# System is broken (login loop and no networking) after update

Tags: networking, wireless, upgrade, login-screen

I ran:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

And after restart, when I typed my password and pressed enter the system froze and then the login screen reappeared. I saw some messages, one of which was something like `Load kernel modules error`.

I'm able to get into tty1 (ctrl+alt+f1). I have tried to update and upgrade using APT again, but WiFi and LAN are not working.

I have tried to start this interfaces but I got `no interface` for eth0 and wlan0, when I try `sudo ifup eth0`

How I can fix my system?

Comment: You might find [this related post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version) useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot and press the Shift key until the Grub menu appears.  Then scroll down to Advanced Options for Ubuntu.  Scroll down to an older kernel without upstart or recovery option and see if it will boot then.

Then you can `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic` and see if it works after a normal reboot